# How to get a node by index in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

AgGrid expects node(s) to be passed in to lot of it's data functions. How do you get a node by index? Look at the snip below:

```
api.forEachNode(function(node){
   api.refreshRows([node]);
})
```

I can pass the `node` parameter to `refreshRows()` function since I'm getting it through `forEachNode()`.

How do you get a node by index without iterating through `forEachNode()` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `getVirtualRow()` method to get a single row. This function is a part of the Row Model. You can get the Row Model by `getModel()` function.

```
var model = api.getModel();
console.log(model.getVirtualRow(idx));
```

Comment: Then be sure to disable sorting/filtering if you do that otherwise you'll have some problems.

Comment: Row Modal has different data sets. It has original rows, rows after filtering and rows after sorting. Ag-grid never modifies original row data after sorting or filtering. Nothing has to be disabled and no problem will occur.

Comment: My bad forget that part. i used mainly server-side load/filtering so it's not the same.

Answer (score 23):

This might be a bit late for this question, but anyway for people who are searching for this in the future :

Apart from the answers given, you can also get the row node by using the following ways,

```
// Getting the row node by the row index
cont rowNode1 = api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
```

In some cases, the above approach is not suitable because the rowIndex can get changed when you do some changes to your grid (sort, filter, etc.).

The other method is to use the id of the row which will not change even if you sort, filter... the grid.

> **getRowNode(id)** : Returns the row node with the given ID. The row node id is the one you provided with the callback getRowNodeId(data), otherwise, the id is a number auto-generated by the grid when the row data is set.

```
// Getting rowNode by row id
const rowNode2 = api.getRowNode(rowId);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that the `idx` will not be accurate in cases the user changes the display order. Please go ahead and add that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Charlie H's answer, it's entirely possible that since the version that he was using, the API has changed a bit. I'm using the (current as of December 2017) version 15.0. I found that `rowsToDisplay[]` contains an array of rows accessible. The following, for example, does exactly what you'd think it would:

```
onCellEditingStarted: function (event) {
    var displayModel = gridOptions.api.getModel();
    var rowNode = displayModel.rowsToDisplay[event.rowIndex];
    rowNode.setRowHeight(100);
    gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
},
```

Comment: I think this is what you need to do in 2022, the methods stated in the docs, and the other answers to this question don't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through the grid row by row in order you can use this (where $scope.grid is your grid name):

```
        $scope.high_index = 0;
        $scope.rows = [];

        $scope.grid.api.forEachNode(function (node) {

            $scope.rows[node.childIndex] = node.id;

            if (node.childIndex > $scope.high_index)
                $scope.high_index = node.childIndex;
        });

        for (i = 0; i <= $scope.high_index; i++) {

            var node = $scope.grid.api.getRowNode($scope.rows[i]);
        }
```

Or if you want a row node by child index you can now use (after setting up $scope.rows above):

```
       var node = $scope.grid.api.getRowNode($scope.rows[i]);
```

Where i is the row number you want.